# Delphi: How to include resources into a component relative to this component

Tags: delphi, components, firemonkey

I'm trying to create a Delphi component. This component needs some images which are included with `{$R *.res *.rc}` in this unit. Additional I have a Delphi BPL project which contains this component. I can compile, build and install this project without problems.

The problem comes when I try to use this component in other projects which are not in the same directory. There I get the error that he could not find the .res-file. Only when I include the .rc-file in these other projects or when I change `{$R *.res *.rc}` to absolute paths it works. But both solutions I don't like. What I want is to include only the .pas-file and then the compiler should find the corresponding resources based on `{$R *.res *.rc}`.

Is this possible and if yes how?

**NOTE**: The path to the .pas- and rc-file is inside of the searchpath. I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle and it is a FMX-component.

Comment: Your resource(s) need to be compiled into the runtime package of your component, and you need to use `FindClassHInstance()` to find the component's correct HInstance handle when loading the resource(s) in code at runtime.